# WebSocket client and WinSock2 server, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, winsock2

I have a c++ server using WinSock2 sockets,
can I connect to this server using JavaScript with WebSocket (as a client), or do I have to use WebSocket in both server and client? how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean? They serve both the TCP/IP protocol, so what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I connect to this server using JavaScript with WebSocket (as a client),

Yes.

> or do I have to use WebSocket in both server and client?

No.

---

Sockets are just implementing an access layer to the IP stack.
How these are implemented at client or server side is irrelevant for establishing and using a (TCP/)IP connection.

Comment: Thanks, I've read more about sockets and I happened to solve my problem, have a good day.